# Ruby: parsing string with backslash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
string = "{:name=>\"2012 Honda Civic EX-L\", :price=>\"23100\", :dealer_name=>\"T AND T HOND\", :dealer_website=>\"http://autocatch.com/dealer/t-and-t-honda/index.htm\", :phone=>\"(888) 364-1858\", :ad=>\"1167269\", :stock=>\" 2120054N\", :year=>\"2012\", :make=>\"Honda\", :model=>\"Model Civic\", :trim=>\"EXL\", :mileage=>\"4629\", :body_style=>\"Coupe\", :transmission=>\"Automatic\", :ext_colour=>\"White\", :int_colour=>\"Grey\", :doors=>\"2Door\", :passengers=>\"Passengers \", :drive_train=>\"Front Wheel Drive\", :engine=>\"1.80\", :cylinders=>\"4Cylinder\", :fuel_type=>\"Type Gas\", :certified=>\"\", :e_tested=>\"\"}\n"
```

How do I parse it?
It keeps giving me error.

Comment: What do you mean by parse? turn it into a hash object, and hash[:name]  stores the string "2012 Honda Civic EX-L" (without the quotes)?

Comment: It means turning into a hash object. It keeps giving errors JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token in.

Comment: This isn't a JSON formatted string, it's a "ruby" one.  Use `Kernel.eval` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The backslashes are just escaping the quotation marks; they aren't actually *in* the string. As for parsing it, use `eval` and let Ruby parse it, if it's from a trusted source.

Answer (score 1):

With **ruby-2.0.0-p0**:

```
string = "{:name=>\"2012 Honda Civic EX-L\", :price=>\"23100\", :dealer_name=>\"T AND T HOND\", :dealer_website=>\"http://autocatch.com/dealer/t-and-t-honda/index.htm\", :phone=>\"(888) 364-1858\", :ad=>\"1167269\", :stock=>\" 2120054N\", :year=>\"2012\", :make=>\"Honda\", :model=>\"Model Civic\", :trim=>\"EXL\", :mileage=>\"4629\", :body_style=>\"Coupe\", :transmission=>\"Automatic\", :ext_colour=>\"White\", :int_colour=>\"Grey\", :doors=>\"2Door\", :passengers=>\"Passengers \", :drive_train=>\"Front Wheel Drive\", :engine=>\"1.80\", :cylinders=>\"4Cylinder\", :fuel_type=>\"Type Gas\", :certified=>\"\", :e_tested=>\"\"}\n"
hash = eval(string)
hash[:name] # => "2012 Honda Civic EX-L"
```

What errors do you get exactly?

Comment: JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token in ... is what I get if I use JSON.parse.

Comment: Maybe try to remove illegal characters with String#encode ? `string.encode("UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "")`